# Do i need to have wudu for English translation of the Quran?

Tags: quran, quran-translation, reading-quran

[image: the Quran]

I am wondering if i need wudu to read this quran as it is mostly english but still has a little quranic surahs in there. I also have another question, if i make dua, does it have to been like a surah from the quran or can i simply ask things like “O Allah please help me with my test tomorrow” etc.

All the surahs as you can see are in english only translation, however at the beginning of the book you can still see there is some Arabic. I must mention that it states it can be also used for dawah purposes. Therefore would i need wudu or not?

Answer (score 1):

If the text is in English only what you have in hand is a translation of the qur'an not the qur'an.
While if there's both Arabic and English side-by-side then the ruling of qur'an being in a tahir state applies, which means if you have not had intercourse nor are in menses or likewise you must perform wudu', else you need to perform ghusl to get your purity (taharah) back and you may perform wudu' too.

That's the "juridical" or fiqh part.

When it comes to respect fro the words of Allah -if you consider it as such- you should consider having wudu' nevertheless.

Imam Malik used to take ghusl if asked about a hadith lesson!